# Tensorflow - use manipulated output of the model in custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensor

today i would like to ask my first question for which i couldn't find a solution in this forum.
I'am new to tensorflow and Neuronal Network programming, so please be patient with me.

Tensorflow-version: 2.3.0

I try to implement a custom loss function in my convolutional network. I know it has to be differentiable and here is my problem.

I implemented a negative pearson correlation as loss and it works (i know because its differentiable):

```
def negPearsonLoss(x,y):
    mean_x = tf.reduce_mean(x)
    mean_y = tf.reduce_mean(y)

    x_1 = x - mean_x
    y_1 = y - mean_y

    s_xy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x_1,y_1))
    s_x = tf.reduce_sum(x_1**2)
    s_y = tf.reduce_sum(y_1**2)
    sx_sy = tf.sqrt(tf.multiply(s_x,s_y))
    
    p = tf.divide(s_xy, sx_sy)
    
    negPearson_coeff = 1. - p

    return negPearson_coeff
```

The output of my NN is a 1D timeseries (in detail a rPPG signal) shape= (N,1).
My idea is know to only use the peaks of the signal (prediction and truth). The error says: *
raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d_2/kernel:0',...
```

My Idea is to use a additional function, executed with the output of the model as input to manipulate the output here. And this tensor would be the input of the loss function.

How can i solve this. I mean, it can't be impossible to change the loss function's input before it's execution, right? I'm totally stuck and spend many hours being confused and desperate. I hope someone can help me.

I read something about tf.gradient_Tape(). but iam using the classical tf.fit function and i don't understand where to put it.

Greetings :)

Comment: The problem is that you are using a lot of operations that are not differentiable, like logic operations, equals, and cast.

Comment: But is there a possibility to use "get_peaks and filt_peaks" on the output snd the ground truth and give the loss fuction only the peaks as input (y_true and y_pred)? the negative pearson correlation works fine...